# Problem with IE8 web accelerator

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

I try to create a web accelerator for IE8. My original XML file was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<os:openServiceDescription xmlns:os="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/openservicedescription/1.0">
  <os:homepageUrl>http://localhost:3090</os:homepageUrl>
  <os:display>
    <os:name>My web accelerator</os:name>
    <os:icon>http://localhost:3090/favicon.ico</os:icon>
  </os:display>
  <os:activity category="Find">
    <os:activityAction context="selection">
      <os:execute method="get" action="http://localhost:3090/Store/SearchResults.aspx?Pattern={selection}" />          
    </os:activityAction>
  </os:activity>
</os:openServiceDescription>
```

It works ok, but when I tried to add "preview" feature, IE8 has reported the error message: "There was a problem with the Accelerator's information."
The modified XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<os:openServiceDescription xmlns:os="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/openservicedescription/1.0">
  <os:homepageUrl>http://localhost:3090</os:homepageUrl>
  <os:display>
    <os:name>My web accelerator</os:name>
    <os:icon>http://localhost:3090/favicon.ico</os:icon>
  </os:display>
  <os:activity category="Find">
    <os:activityAction context="selection">
      <os:execute method="get" action="http://localhost:3090/Store/SearchResults.aspx?Pattern={selection}" />
      <os:preview action = "http://localhost:3090/OpenService/Accelerator.aspx" method = "get">
        <os:parameter name="q" value="{selection}" type="text" />
      </os:preview>
    </os:activityAction>
  </os:activity>
</os:openServiceDescription>
```

What's wrong with added XML fragment?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved.
IE8 does not support "localhost" as target domain for links in the action attributes, for some unknown reasons. I have replaced all links to non-local domain name and it starts working. Unfortunately, since then I cannot efficiently debug my web accelerator like it was run under the Visual Studio Development Web Server.